# How to optimize the following query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was trying to optimize the following query. The two sub queries that are being used can i make it into single query.

```
select fn.id,
(select top 1 s.rid from find f join status s on f.fid = s.fid 
                    where f.fid = fn.id and f.active = 1) as rid,
(select top 1 f.gid from find f 
                    where f.fid = fn.id and f.active = 1) as gid
           from finding fn where f.tid = 'abcd'
```

I have used CWE for join subquery because it gets executed over and over for each iteration but i want to ask some DBA experts here, what could be the possible and optimum solution for the following query to be optimized. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `OUTER APPLY`

```
SELECT fn.id, 
       oa.rid, 
       oa.gid 
FROM   finding fn 
       OUTER apply (SELECT TOP 1 s.rid, 
                                 f.gid 
                    FROM   find f 
                           JOIN status s 
                             ON f.fid = s.fid 
                    WHERE  f.fid = fn.id 
                           AND f.active = 1) oa 
WHERE  f.tid = 'abcd'
```

**Note:** You are using `TOP 1` with out `Order by` you will get arbitrary records in result .

Answer (score 0):

This should perform better:

```
select fn.id, t.rid, t.gid
from finding fn 
join (
   select f.fid, s.rid, f.gid,
          row_number() over (order by select null) as rn 
   from find f 
   join status s on f.fid = s.fid 
   where f.active = 1
) as t on t.fid = fn.id and rn = 1
where fn.tid = 'abcd'
```

The `TOP 1` in the original query is executed without an `ORDER BY` clause, so it is not clear which record should be selected. You can substitute `select null` in the above query with the field that determines the top row selection.

Comment: In case OP has index on `ID` column, still I think it will scan all the records for each `ID` to generate `Row_number`